# Python Tkinter: Is there a way prevent 'Label' text from pushing columns to the side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Python's Tkinter library tool. Currently I'm trying to output text on a screen when a user enters proper login credentials to a server node. I'm using `grid` instead of `pack` when I organize things around this GUI.

**Is there a way to prevent `Label` text from pushing columns to the side?**

---

This is what the current GUI looks like:

[image]

... and here's what happens when I "login" to the server node with some confirmation text on the screen:

[image]

... and this is what I'm wishing would happen instead (photoshopped):

[image]

... and using @Bryan Oakley's feedback (small difference):

[image]

I could move the text on the second column, `column=1`, but there are things to the right of textbox  entry modules (that I won't show in this question). My initial thought that perhaps there is some layer priority with GUIs so maybe I could set the text at the bottom layers so that it wouldn't affect the textboxes but I haven't found anything with [Tkinter's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) on how to do this.

---

Here's some of my code:

```
import json
import requests
import sys
import os
import time
import threading
import getpass
import warnings
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

nodeIPLabel = Label(text = 'Node IP/Hostname :   ')
nodeIPLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky='W')
nodeUsernameLabel = Label(text = 'Node username :   ')
nodeUsernameLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky='W')
nodePasswordLabel = Label(text = 'Node passwword :   ')
nodePasswordLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky='W')

# Enter Login Credentials
nodeIP = StringVar()
nodeUsername = StringVar()
nodePassword = StringVar()

nodeIPEntry = Entry(textvariable = nodeIP, width = 30)
nodeIPEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky='W')
nodeUsernameEntry = Entry(textvariable = nodeUsername, width = 30)
nodeUsernameEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky='W')
nodePasswordEntry = Entry(textvariable = nodePassword, width = 30, show = '*')
nodePasswordEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky='W')

def nodeLogin():
    global nodeIP
    nodeIP = nodeIP.get()
    global nodeUsername
    nodeUsername = nodeUsername.get()
    global nodePassword
    nodePassword = nodePassword.get()
    global nodeType
    nodeType = nodeType.get()
    nodeURL = 'https://' + nodeIP

    try:
        listOfStuff = '%s/redfish/v1/Chassis/1' % nodeURL
        response = requests.get(listOfStuff, auth=(nodeUsername, nodePassword), verify=False)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('Connection successful!')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
       connectionStatus = Label(text='Connection failure: Incorrect or nonexisting IP/Hostname. Hit "RESET GUI" to restart.', fg = 'red')
       connectionStatus.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky='N')

    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
        connectionStatus = Label(text='Connection failure: Nothing was typed in. Hit "RESET GUI" to restart.', fg = 'red')
        connectionStatus.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky='N')

    except KeyError:
        connectionStatus = Label(text='Connection failure: Wrong login credentials. Hit "RESET GUI" to restart.', fg = 'red')
        connectionStatus.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky='N')

    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        connectionStatus = Label(text='Connection failure: Unknown error... Hit "RESET GUI" to restart.', fg = 'red')
        connectionStatus.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky='N')

def resetGUI():
    os.startfile(__file__)
    sys.exit()

# Login button
nodeLoginButton = Button(text = 'LOGIN', command = nodeLogin, bg = 'green', width = 20)
nodeLoginButton.grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky='W')

# Reset script button
resetButton = Button(text = 'RESET GUI', command = resetGUI, bg = 'yellow', width = 20)
resetButton.grid(column = 0, row = 5, sticky = 'W')

# Stop script button
stopButton = Button(text = 'EMERGENCY STOP', command = window.destroy, bg = 'red', width = 20)
stopButton.grid(column = 0, row = 6, sticky = 'W')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in this specific case is to have that bottom label span more than one column.

```
connectionStatus.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky='N', columnspan=2)
```

Of course, that assumes you're only using 2 columns. If you're using more, adjust `columnspan` to fit your overall design.

However, even that's not enough if the text is literally too long to fit in the window. In that case, you need to give the widget a fixed size. When you do that, the contents of the label won't cause the label to change size.

Typically what I do for a widget like this is give it a size of one, have the label span all of the columns you are using, and then use the `sticky` attribute to have the widget "stick" to the sides of the space allocated to it. That will cause the label to grow to fit the space, but because you've given an explicit requested size, changing the text won't change the size of the label.

That being said, an even simpler approach is to divide your window into two parts: the top part would be a frame with all of the widgets, and the bottom part with just the label. You can then use `pack` to arrange the top and bottom parts easily, and then you can use `grid` to lay out the widgets in the frame, but because the label is outside the frame it won't affect anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This works better but it still pushes the column to the right but not nearly as much as before.... and I also tried `sticky=W`... same results.

Comment: Ah... Just need to make `columnspan` larger... Thanks :)